# Redirect a user to a different page from f:event listener method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have following code for initializing bean values depending upon url parameter.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{inningBean.inningId}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" 
        listener="#{inningBean.initInningBeanForBallByBallScoring}" />
</f:metadata>
```

This is working fine. But I want that in certain conditions(some validation forexample), the user is redirected to another page from listener method.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29).

```
public void initInningBeanForBallByBallScoring() throws IOException {
    // ...

    if (someCondition) {
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/other.xhtml");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for answer. Can we add facesmessages for that page?

Comment: You're welcome. Only through the flash scope if it's in the same path.

Comment: I want to add facesMessage in this listener function so that they are shown on redirected page. (The redirected page has necessary messages tag and that is working from within that page's controlls action methods). Can you please help with my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10595760/517491