# jsf IllegalStateException on redirect even with return

Tags: jsf, redirect, servlet-3.0

In my `preRenderView` invoked method some validations are performed and if it fails a redirect shall happen.

But i am getting an `IllegalStateException`

```
Information: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:524)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.redirect(ExternalContextImpl.java:602)
    at package.FacesContextUtils.redirect(FacesContextUtils.java:581)
```

Here is the code:

```
public void initPreRenderView(final String value) throws DatabaseException
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        FacesContextUtils.addMessageInvalidLinkRedirect(context, url);
        return;
    }
}
```

Basically the utility function consists of:

```
public static void addMessageInvalidLinkRedirect(FacesContext context, String url)
{
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Invalid link..."));
    try
    {
        context.getExternalContext().redirect(url);
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        // add error message
    }
}
```

Many answers regarding this topic suppose to add a return after the redirection statement, which I did in the preRenderView method.

**Edit:**

The redirection takes place and everything works as expected. Just want to get rid of this error message.

Comment: Why are you trying to redirect before rendering the view to begin with?

Comment: The user is not supposed to visit that view without a valid view-param. This case should never happen but if user manipulates url by hand it still can happen.

Comment: You can use a validator for your `<f:viewParam>`. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/4888942/1065197

Comment: I know about it but even if it fails User will stay on same page. But there are multiple view-params where validation depends on each other. My requirement is necessary. There are even more use cases to check for session scoped content and the sites have no content and no use-case if this kind of validation fails. I must redirect to most valid parent page in this case.

Comment: Then you should use a Filter instead.

Comment: As far as I know filter occurs before viewscoped bean creation or not? So i do not have access to my necessary properties and cannot implement the validation.

Comment: But you will have access to the request parameters as well. That's what you want to validate, or not?

Comment: Basically yes but the view-params are POJO with converters. Rebuilding the logic within a filter is just a waste of time. Redirecting within preRenderEvent is a basic pattern to perform complex validations so lets keep it this way. I just want to get rid of the exception. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582441/redirect-a-user-to-a-different-page-from-fevent-listener-method

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the presence or absence of the return statement. The problem is that the response cannot be reset. Let's look where this is caused:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:524)
```

Based on [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.37/org/apache/catalina/connector/ResponseFacade.java#479) this will be thrown when `isCommitted()` returns `true`. Thus, the response is already committed. A part of the response has already been sent to the client.

There's nothing in your question which indicates that. So, the cause of the problem has to be sought elsewhere than in the information provided so far. On standard JSF this should not happen, so perhaps you've somewhere a servlet filter which is setting/committing some headers?

Comment: What do you mean by setting/committing some headers? I am using your NoCacheFilter from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101380/jsf-back-button-refresh-page. Else I am using some authentication filters to check if user is logged in and redirect if not. I will check this out.

Comment: Did not hat time for it to check again but this error does not always occurs someties it doesnt, then it occurs but still redirects (only in log) and other time error is shown on site. Is it possible that my system is just to slow sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar issue. The problem turned out being that another redirect request was being made before I invoked the one I expected. Because one redirect request had already been made it threw an IllegalStateException.